# How to retrive comman sperated value from same input feild name in django

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, post

I have following html

```
<input name='Test' value='Maths'/>
<input name='Test' value='PHP'/>
```

And want to retrieve request data using

```
 Test = request.POST.getlist(["Test"])
```

Or

```
 Test = request.POST.get(["Test"])
```

When i am tried this both statement gives error
**unhashable type: 'list'**

Or if i used simple

```
Test = request.POST(["Test"])
```

it only return last value i.e **PHP**

Is there any other way to retrieve value ?

Comment: can you do try without `[]` ?

Comment: Its Work.Thanks For your help